# Any newer version of sonar-bitbucket-plugin for sonarqube-7.5?

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket

My organization is using sonarqube:7.1 with sonar-bitbucket-plugin-1.2.3 (https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin) and everything is working fine. We are planning to upgrade to sonarqube:7.5 and while I was testing all the existing plugins, sonar-bitbucket-plugin is causing the issue(It's not supported in the newer version of Sonarqube). I want to upgrade to 7.5+ version of Sonarqube and want sonar-bitbucket-plugin as well. Could someone please help me out?

ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin Bitbucket for Sonar [sonarbitbucket]

Answer (score 2):

This community plugin was relying on the deprecated preview/issues analysis mode to analyze pull requests, that was finally removed.

Since SonarQube 6.7 the support of branches (and then pull requests) analysis has been properly integrated on the server side. Decorating PR was added progressively for various ALM, and for Bitbucket Server it is supported [since 7.7](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-7/).

Note that all branch/PR features are only available in commercial editions (or for free on SonarCloud for open source projects).